# How to assign positions to get winning team/group

Tags: php, mysql

I want to assign the finish places for a tournament a set of points where First place gets 10 points, Second 9 points, and so on. Then I want to combine the points of the players that share the same team name and anyone with no team (null) gets no points. Then return the team name (team.title) and id (team.team_id) of which has the most points.

```
$TOTW = $db->fetchAll("SELECT tournyplayer.finishplace, user.username, team.title as teamname, team_member.member_state ".
                    "FROM tournyplayer ".
                    "JOIN user ON user.user_id = tournyplayer.userid ".
                    "LEFT JOIN team_member ON team_member.user_id = user.user_id ".
                    "LEFT JOIN team ON team.team_id = team_member.team_id ".
                    "JOIN tourny ON tourny.id = tournyplayer.multitrnyid ".
                    "WHERE tourny.title = 'Team Game' ".
                    "ORDER BY tourny.endtime DESC, tournyplayer.finishplace ASC ".
                    "LIMIT 10");
    // Used for testing results     
    foreach($TOTW AS $rowName => $results){
    if ($results["teamname"] === null OR $results["member_state"] === "request") $results["teamname"] = '-';
    print "<pre>";
    echo '<h1 align="center"><b>' . $results['username'] . '</b> finished ' . $results['finishplace'] . ' from Team ' . $results['teamname'] . '</h1>';
    print "</pre><br />";
}
```

Which returns something similar.

```
+-------------+----------+----------+
| finishplace | username | teamname |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      1      |  Andy    |  Team B  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      2      |  Bob     |  Team B  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      3      |  Cole    |  NULL    |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      4      |  Dillon  |  Team A  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      5      |  Ernie   |  Team A  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      6      |  Frank   |  Team A  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      7      |  George  |  Team C  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      8      |  Herman  |  NULL    |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      9      |  Ike     |  Team B  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|      10     |  Joe     |  Team A  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

With this example Team A gets 19 points, Team B gets 21 Points, Team C gets 4 points and the other two members get 0 points for not being on a team. So Team B will be the winning team as they have the most points. In a circumstance where 2 or more teams have the same points, the "tie breaker" would be determined by the team that had the highest placed member.

I was only able to get the results to work in by dumb luck and a couple hours trying to figure out joins as I'm still learning MySQL and PHP. I'm not sure what to do from here since I'm just starting out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not going to write the code for you, but will provide some hints so that you can solve the problem. If the hints is not sufficient for you, please share the tables details and I will try to provide you the actual sql.

You need to do couple trick in here. The point for a person is 10-finishplace-1. So add a column with the formula in your select query. Once you have this query ready, you can create a view with this query and then use simple select sum() query with group by teamname.

Alternatively you can use sub query for this. However, view is efficient then subquery.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. Not sure if its 100% what you meant but I made a new table with the points to join on finish place and I used sum and group by to add the teams points. which turns out exactly what I want. From there how would I do a tie breaker using the highest placed member of each team?

Comment: You can use a order by in the query to order the data for multiple columns. If you share the table details, I can give you better suggestion.